# Retrieve Junit test expected result

Tags: java, junit

I'm writing Junit test cases for a bunch of classes; each of them has a handful of method to test. The classes I'm about to test look like the following.

```
class A{
    int getNth(int n);
    int getCount();
}

class B{
    int[] getAllNth(int n);
    int getMin();
}
```

I store the expected result for each `class.method()` in a file. For example, in a CSV,

```
A; getNth(1):7;        getNth(2):3;          getCount():3
B; getAllNth(2):[7,3]; getAllNth(3):[7,3,4]; getMin():3
```

My question is how can retrieve those value easily in test cases. I hope to pass the method call `A.getNth(2)` to a class that can build a string `"A.getNth(2)"`

If the format I store the data is not ideal, free feel to give suggestion on that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to use [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about JUnit, but here is how you would do it with [TestNG](http://testng.org), using data providers:

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] dp() {
  return new Object[][] {
    new Object[] { 1, 7 },
    new Object[] { 2, 3 },
  };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
public nthShouldMatch(int parameter, int expected) {
  Assert.assertEquals(getNth(parameter), expected);
}
```

Obviously, you should implement dp() in a way that it retrieves its values from the spreadsheet instead of hardcoding them like I just did, but you get the idea. Once you have implemented your data provider, all you need to do is update your spreadsheet and you don't even need to recompile your code.